# OpenLayers data moves when panning map

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I have an OpenLayers map.

On to this I have loaded a GeoJSON file.

When I pan the map the GeoJSON data moves relative to the basemap.

Surely this isn't right! Can anyone shed some light no why this is happening?

Comment: please add a link to your code, it's very hard to debug from just a description of the problem

Comment: to add to what @iant said - you can use http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/  to post some bare bones code to test.

Comment: Surley you want your georeferenced data to move relative to the other spatial data?

Comment: We are waiting for the code, but it appears normal to me that the geojson data move when panning the basemap ...

Comment: questioner is complaining the data moves *relative* to the base map - it's probably a projection issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened to me once and the layer was not on the same projection as the basemap.

But without example code, this is like a stab in the dark.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the problem now - which is good - but I am having a slightly different problem. Now the overlays are aligned correctly (over Britain) when using osgeo.org basemap but are off the coast of Africa (0,0 in EPSG:4326 projection) when using Google or Microsoft. I'm almost certain it is a projection issue. I'll mark this as the correct answer - I can't reproduce the original problem so I can't test any other answers. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause of this is not setting a baselayer's sphericalMercator property to true - by default this is false, so it needs to be set explicitly.

```
var myBaseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google",
              {'sphericalMercator': true
              });
```

> APIProperty: sphericalMecator Whether
>   the tile extents should be set to the
>   defaults for  spherical mercator.
>   Useful for things like OpenStreetMap.
>   Default is false, except for the OSM
>   subclass.